# the server is a J2EE web service and MySQL is the database server, client and J2EE server are in different time zones

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

We are working on a client – server environment where the client is a J2SE app, the server is a J2EE web service and MySQL is the database server, client and J2EE server are in different time zones and java is performing an automatic time zone conversion in client side but we want the client to work in the same time zone as the server with no conversions. Any ideas on how we can do this?

Comment: Please post more information about the data format and transfer protocol.

You probably just need to append timezone information to your time/date values.

Comment: What is wrong with just changing the timezone of jvm of the client to the one you want?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best you can do is store and process the data always in UTC and only display them in the demanded locale.